# Epsilon-Delta proof for continuous point and function

Tags: calculus

How do you prove the following?

If $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=L$ and $f$ is continuous at $x=L$, then
$$\lim_{x\to c}f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x\to c}g(x)) = f(L).$$

What I have so far is that since $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=L$, $f(\lim_{x\to c}g(x))$  = $f(L)$. So now I need to prove either $\lim_{x\to c}f(g(x)) = f(\lim_{x\to c}g(x))$ or  $\lim_{x\to c}f(g(x))$ = $f(L)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$
0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(g(x))-f(L)| <\varepsilon.
$$

To do this we will fix a positive $\varepsilon$.
Since $f$ is continuous at $L$, we know that there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that
$$
|x-L| < \delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(L)| < \varepsilon. \tag{1}
$$
Since $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=L$, there is $\delta_2>0$ such that
$$
0<|x-c|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)-L|<\delta_1. \tag{2}
$$
Putting both of these together, we conclude that
$$
0<|x-c|<\delta_2
\stackrel{(2)}{\implies} |g(x)-L|<\delta_1
\stackrel{(1)}{\implies} |f(g(x))-f(L)|<\varepsilon,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Why is it |g(x)−L|<δ1 rather than |g(x)−L|<ε in the third line? Also, how did you get from |g(x)−L|<δ1 to |f(g(x))−f(L)|<ε in the last line? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @calconfused I chose to apply the definition of $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=L$ to $\delta_1$ instead of to $\varepsilon$ because we needed $|g(x)-L|$ to be less than $\delta_1$ in order to apply $(1)$. Since the definition of limit works for any positive value, it is okay to do this. As for your second question, I am just applying $(1)$ with $g(x)$ playing the role of $x$.